# Install CakePHP in a subdirectory of Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have 2 frameworks in a single website. I am using cakephp in subdirectory of codeigniter like:

```
application
cakephp
systems
html
...
```

here cakephp is the folder where I put my code of cakephp. This structure is work fine in localhost but Its not working in live server.

my root htaccess code (codeigniter) is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cakephp/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and cakephp htaccess is look like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

now when I try `www.example.com` then It works fine but it doesnt work for `www.example.com/cakephp` or `www.example.com/cakephp/index.php` or `www.example.com/cakephp/login`. It shows blank page or result like: `No input file specified.`

Comment: What do you mean by *it doesn't work*?

Comment: sorry for late reply .... actually it shows blank page

Comment: Then I doubt if it doesn't work. Please take a look at `php_errors.log` at the first or enable error reporting functionality if it is off.

Comment: I think its mode-rewrite issue...that should be solved

Comment: It wouldn't be `mod_rewrite`. A blank page leads us to be concerned about PHP more than anything else.

Comment: when i tried htaccess for cakephp folder like `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine  on 
  RewriteRule ^/backend$       backend/app/webroot/     [L] 
  RewriteRule ^/backend/(.*)$ backend/app/webroot/$1  [L] 
</IfModule>` then it works.... means it shows data but now it dont get any css or js

Comment: I didn't see your edit where you said about `No input file specified.`. Please add `RewriteBase /` to your CI .htaccess file and let me know what happens.

Comment: What is `backend` then?

Comment: sorry... consider backend as cakephp